# CORS error while trying to connect to S3 from a rails app using TextureLoader

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, three.js, cors

This has been driving me nuts. I have googled/binged/altavistad(not really!) but unable to make any significant progress. 
I have a script to load a texture onto a sphere.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

//allow cross origin loading
loader.crossOrigin = '';
loader.load(window.photo_url,
// Function when resource is loaded
  function ( texture ) { 
    sphereMaterial.map = texture;
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, sphereMaterial);
    scene.add(sphereMesh);
    // Start the update frame part
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
)
```

The window.photo_url is set in another code snippet. 
My S3 bucket is now at its most permissive CORS configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

However this does not work consistently and gives a COR related error from time to time. The page works on both Chrome and Safari on my laptop. However on my phone, it works on Chrome works but does not work on Safari. On another phone the page does not work either on Chrome and Safari.  Interestingly on the same page, I have images loading using image_tag from the same s3 bucket and they show up. In fact one of the images is the one I am trying to use in the script above and when fetched using image_tag it shows up fine.

Any one faced similar issues? Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: The error show in the console in Chrome is:  

Access to Image at 'https://xxxxxamazonaws.com/uploads/88b12c8c-1829-45fa-93a3-63e7cdb83bca/EventCenterFront.jpg' from origin 'yyyy' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'yyyy' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging around some more, I ended up writing a simple image proxy on my server.

Answer (score 0):

In the core, try to change the loader to:

```
loader.setCrossOrigin( "anonymous" );
```

Comment: how is that different from what I am already doing in the "loader.crossOrigin = ''; " line? I have tried anonymous as well.

Answer (score 0):

To test, instead of using wildcard `*`, try putting your origin in permission.
e.g:`<AllowedOrigin>http://127.0.0.1:8000</AllowedOrigin>`.

A browser would block JavaScript from allowing `GET/PUT/DELETE/POST` **requests** in case domain is not the same for API requests.

However, images loaded using `<img>` tag is not restricted and pretty much can request images from anywhere on web. Same applied for loading assets like external CSS/JavaScript files.

Comment: Hi Aniket, I started with my site in it but as that did not work i went to the wildcard